# Spring Data query returns null but SQL query returns value

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data

I have a persistent class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@Table(name = "REGION")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = IRegionRepo.QUERY_NAME.findPropertyValue, query = IRegionRepo.QUERY.findPropertyValue)
})
public class Region extends NameClassifier {

    /** The Constant serialVersionUID. */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** The countries. */
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "REGION_COUNTRY", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "REGION"),     inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY"))
private Set<Country> countries;

    /** The properties. */
    @ElementCollection
    @JoinTable(name = "REGION_PROPERTY", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "REGION"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "PROPERTY_NAME")
    @Column(name = "PROPERTY_VALUE")
    private Map<String, String> properties;
}
```

And the String Data repository:

```
public final static String findPropertyValue = "select VALUE(rp) from Region r join r.properties rp "
            + "where :country MEMBER OF r.countries and KEY(rp)=:property";

@Query(name = QUERY_NAME.findPropertyValue)
public String findTopPropertyValue(@Param("country") final Country country, @Param("property") final String property);
```

When I run the method, with certain parameters, it returns null.
However, if I substitute the parameters into the generated SQL query and run it in SQL*Plus, it does return a value.

What could be the issue?

The query generated:

```
select properties1_.property_value as col_0_0_ 
from region region0_ inner join region_property properties1_ on  region0_.id=properties1_.region 
where (? in (select countries2_.country from region_country countries2_ where region0_.id=countries2_.region)) and properties1_.property_name=?;
```

Comment: log query and params to be sure that you have properly params 
`logging:
  level:
    org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
    org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder: TRACE`

Comment: @ShakirovRamil, this is where the problem is. I log queries, I trace parameters. When I run the query with substituted parameters, it does return expected result. But the repository method called with same parameters returns null

Answer (score 0):

Its probably happening because of transactions not commited yet

Can you update your question with where you used this method
`findTopPropertyValue`

Comment: No, those data change very rarely. This is not the case